# Check if flag is set in integer variable

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I am making my own simple drawing engine. I am trying to determine if a variable has been set to a specific value using what I think is called bitwise comparison but I maybe wrong.

I've always been a bit confused about what the following is and how I use it:

```
int DRAW_REPEAT_X = 70001; // I have a feeling I should make this value binary instead of a unique number, ie, 0
int DRAW_REPEAT_Y = 70002; // I have a feeling I should make this value binary instead of a unique number, ie, 2
int drawMethod    = DRAW_REPEAT_X | DRAW_REPEAT_Y; // this means I want to repeat an image on both the x and y axis doesn't it?

// Now I want to check if drawMethod has DRAW_REPEAT_X set: this is where I struggle to know how to check this
// Is the following correct?
if (drawMethod && DRAW_REPEAT_X) {
  // the user wants me to repeat an image along the x axis
}

// Now I want to check if drawMethod has DRAW_REPEAT_Y set: this is where I struggle to know how to check this
if (drawMethod && DRAW_REPEAT_Y) {
  // the user wants me to repeat an image along the x axis
}
```

**Is the following code correctly checking if DRAW_REPEAT_X is set?** It always returns 1 in my anding check.

*EDIT*
And to check whether both bits are set do I do this?

```
if (drawMethod & DRAW_REPEAT_X & DRAW_REPEAT_Y) {
   // both set
}

// OR

if (drawMethod & DRAW_REPEAT_X && drawMethod & DRAW_REPEAT_Y) {
   // both set
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it isn't, you should use the bitwise AND operator instead - `&` and set the flags as binary values - your intuition is correct on that side.

A common trick to setting specific bits is using the shift operator:

```
int DRAW_REPEAT_X = 0x1 << 0;  //first bit set to 1, others 0
int DRAW_REPEAT_Y = 0x1 << 1;  //second bit set to 1, others 0
```

and check the int as

```
if (drawMethod & DRAW_REPEAT_X)  //check it that particular flag is set, ignore others
{
}
```

Comment: @ouah if you count bits from 0, then yes. But talking about the first bit, second bit and so on makes more sense to me. I think the message is clear though. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 10):

For this to work, your flag variables each need to have a single, unique bit set.  That bit is the "flag".  For constants where it's the bitwise representation that matters, it's much more convenient to use hexadecimal or octal (because these bases are a power of 2) than decimal.  So, for example:

```
enum {
    DRAW_REPEAT_X = 0x01,    /* First bit set */
    DRAW_REPEAT_Y = 0x02,    /* Second bit set */
    DRAW_MIRRORED = 0x04,    /* Third bit set */
};

int drawMethod = DRAW_REPEAT_X | DRAW_REPEAT_Y;  /* Will have both first and second bits set */
```

Then you use bitwise-and `&` rather than logical-and `&&` to test the bits.  `a & b` will be non-zero if and only if there is at least one bit that is set in both `a` and `b`.  In the case of testing for a flag, one of these will have only one bit set - the flag you're interested in - so the result of `a & flag` will be non-zero if and only if the flag is set in `a`:

```
if (drawMethod & DRAW_REPEAT_X) {
  // the user wants me to repeat an image along the x axis
}

if (drawMethod & DRAW_REPEAT_Y) {
  // the user wants me to repeat an image along the x axis
}
```

The hexadecimal pattern for constants with one bit set is `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x04`, `0x08`, `0x10`, `0x20`, ...

Comment: @Jake M and viewers from the future: Just don't get confused and set `DRAW_REPEAT_Z = 0x03;` following 0x01 and 0x02 ! **That would be wrong**. The important thing is to enumerate your flags ONLY as powers of 2. e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 (in decimal/base 10). Using octals and hexes is impressive but there is no point to it prior to digesting this fact. It would have been intuitive to use binary e.g. 0b001 0b010 0b100 (see how the beautiful bits pass a-floating) alas is non-standard, supported by GCC only - though with a new C standard sprouting every day someone would have "standardised" it by now.

Comment: @bliako: I have updated the answer slightly to hopefully clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands right now, you aren't using flags so much as having a value that indicates a method. Much better is to use some sort of bits, like this:

```
int DRAW_REPEAT_X=0x01;
int DRAW_REPEAT_Y=0x02;
```

And then check the ifs like you are doing now, but with a single &

```
if (drawMethod & DRAW_REPEAT_X)
```

Typically, your integers (`DRAW_REPEAT_X`) should be `public static`, if you are working with a class architecture. But not knowing if that is the case, I won't include them

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet using the WinAPIs that shows setting two flags to a value, and then checking for the existence of at least one of those flags in that value. It should `return 0;`

```
INPUT mip;
mip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mip.mi.mouseData = 0;
mip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

if (mip.mi.dwFlags & (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL))
    return 0;
```

If you want to check for an exact value combination, you don't need to use the bitwise operator `&`, and can do a simple `==` check.

For example, the updated line near the bottom

```
INPUT mip;
mip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mip.mi.mouseData = 0;
mip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

if (mip.mi.dwFlags == (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE))
    return 0;
```