# Flags - Check if bits are set and only those bits are set

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

According to other questions on Stack Overflow, we can check if a bit flag is set using:

```
if(value & flag)
```

[Check if flag is set in integer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464063/check-if-flag-is-set-in-integer-variable)

[Checking for bit flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872589/checking-for-bit-flags)

[C/C++ check if one bit is set in, i.e. int variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523724/c-c-check-if-one-bit-is-set-in-i-e-int-variable)

However, I want to check if particular flags are set and if only the bits that make up those flags are set.

```
static const uint64_t SOMEFLAG_0 = 0x0;
static const uint64_t SOMEFLAG_1 = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint64_t SOMEFLAG_2 = 0x1 << 1;
static const uint64_t SOMEFLAG_3 = 0x1 << 2;
static const uint64_t SOMEFLAG_4 = 0x1 << 3;
```

My attempt was:

```
if ((value & ~(SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4)) == 0)
```

However, that won't work in the case flag 1 is set and flag 4 is not set. I want to test if the are both set and no other bits are set.

How do I perform that test in a conventional manner?
Perhaps I want to XOR the value and the mask and do something?

Comment: How about `value == required_flags`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the simplest answer eludes you after having your mind wrapped in complicated things.

This is enough:

```
if(value == flag)
```

And if you need to check multiple flags:

```
if(value == (SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4))
            ^                       ^
            important               important
```

And don't forget to enclose the bitwise operations in parenthesis. The precedence is unexpected and without them `value == SOMEFLAG_1` would be evaluated first.

---

And I guess this is a perfect time for preaching for enabling (and paying attention to) compiler warnings:

clang has a very helpful one `-Wparentheses` which is included in `-Wall`:

> 5 : :5:28: warning: | has lower precedence than ==; == will be
>   evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
>
> ```
> if(value == SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4)
>    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> ```
>
> 5 : :5:28: note: place parentheses around the '==' expression
>   to silence this warning
>
> ```
> if(value == SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4)
>                        ^
>    (                  )
> ```
>
> 5 : :5:28: note: place parentheses around the | expression to
>   evaluate it first
>
> ```
> if(value == SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4)
>                        ^
>             (                      )
> ```

gcc has it also:

> 5 : :5:14: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in
>   operand of '|' [-Wparentheses]
>
> ```
>  if(value == SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4)
>     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. It's:

```
if ((value & (SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4)) == (SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4))
```

Of course this assumes you don't care what `SOMEFLAG2` or 3 are. If that's also the case (that you care about all bits), then:

```
if (value == (SOMEFLAG_1 | SOMEFLAG_4))
```